# Loading bar is displayed when I use WinJS.UI.ListView with WinJS.UI.ListLayout

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have created very simple nav project with ListView. When I use ListLayout it doesn't display my data. Instead it displays loading bar. When I use GridLayout everything is ok. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to set up your databinding? One possibility is that when you switch to ListLayout, you may not be setting the dataSource correctly.

Comment: `<div class="tickets-list" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ 
                itemDataSource: abc.dataSource, 
                selectionMode: 'none', 
                tapBehavior: 'invoke',
                swipeBehavior: 'none',
                layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout },
                itemTemplate: select('.simpleTemplate')
                }"></div>` and `var abc = new WinJS.Binding.List([{ a: 'a' }, { a: 'b' }]);`. I have recreated project and everything works fine.

Comment: Glad it's working now. For future reference, probably better to edit your question and update it with the code, rather than putting the code in a comment, where the formatting isn't very readable.